# Chrome Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in Chrome when I log some firebase get function snapshot, and couldn't find a way to properly solve this.

I'm trying to convert the object with JSON.stringify and results this

```
VM310:1 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'FirebaseAppImpl'
|     property 'firebase_' -> object with constructor 'Object'
|     property 'apps' -> object with constructor 'Array'
--- index 0 closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:1:11
```

EDIT:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection('allPosts')
        .doc(thisPost.id)
        .collection('likes')
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot)
            
            })
```

Comment: You are trying to stringify a circular object. Can you share your code so we can see what's that?

Comment: It's a firestore request, and I just simply logged the snapshot

Comment: Can you please share that block of code ?

Comment: Added edit! @Dharmaraj